# Finding articulatory profiles

Tags: phonetics, resource-request, articulation

I have two questions. The first is how is it better to call such pictures? Is the term 'articulatory profile' alright? The second: is there a place on the internet or elsewhere which contains many pictures of that kind for various sounds of different languages? I'm aware of, e.g., https://www.seeingspeech.ac.uk/ipa-charts/ but that's not exactly it.

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, pictures like that are referred to as "sagittal sections" (sagittal referring to being split down the plane dividing left from right).

If you want an interactive cartoon of sagittal sections in phonetics, you might want to check out http://smu-facweb.smu.ca/~s0949176/sammy/. Similarly, this youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFuOFZ0wFoHK2deKFldaLGA does a lot of videos phoneme by phoneme on a cartoonish sagittal section.

If you want videos that use an MRI to take sagittal sections of people talking, this youtube playlist has a bunch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8yysjQeYT4&list=PL7TNe5tKMpG6S57Gn7AszyRhDNOyjlcBv.

Answer (score 0):

A brief note on terminology. The pictures like the one in question are also called mid-sagittal (or, informally, head) diagrams and can be found in different works on phonetics or speech science. For example, many of them for the Russian language are given in the book called *A conspectus of Russian speech sounds* by K. Bolla.